# How do I set up a Tab Bar Controller within an existing Navigation Controller?

Tags: uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I'm pretty new to iOS. I'm building an app and am running into an issue. I have a navigation controller with a table view controller atop its stack. When I select a row in that table view controller, what I'd like to see is a collection view with the following:

- The nav bar with the name that appears on the selected cell as the navigation item title.
- A collection view as the main interface
- a tab bar with the collection view, and an imagePickerController

Here's what my code looks like:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{


    NewTabBarController *tbc = [[NewTabBarController alloc] init];

    UIImagePickerController *takeAPicture = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];

UITabBarItem *tabItem = [takeAPicture tabBarItem];
    [tabItem setImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:@"CameraIcon.jpg"]];
    [tabItem setTitle:@"Take a photo!"];

    UICollectionViewFlowLayout *photoFlow = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
    PhotoCollectionViewController *photoHub = [[PhotoCollectionViewController alloc] initWithCollectionViewLayout:photoFlow];

    [tbc setViewControllers:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:photoHub, takeAPicture, nil]];

    NSArray *items = [[items accessor] allItems];

    Item *item = [items objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];

    [photoHub setItem:item];
    [photoHub useLayoutToLayoutNavigationTransitions];


    [[self navigationController] pushViewController:tbc animated:YES];

}
```

Then in my PhotoCollectionViewController implementation I have:

```
@syntesize item;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

UINavigationItem *itemHeader = [self navigationItem];
    [itemHeader setTitle:[item itemName]];

    UITabBarItem *tabItem = [self tabBarItem];
    [tabItem setImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:@"itemImage.jpg"]];
    [tabItem setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Photos of %@", [item itemName]]];

}
```

My problem is that when I select the cell, The collection view loads, and I can see the cells I have set up in the collection view, but the nav bar item has no title, and the tab bar item has "Photos of (null)" and no image. The "Take a photo!" text appears, but the image does not.

Do you guys have any idea how I can restructure this to make everything flow correctly. I must be doing something wrong in the way I'm utilizing tab and nav controllers.I don't want there to be any tabs until this stage in the app, which is 3 or 4 VCs in already. Should I be using a tab bar controller from the App Delegate onward?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that you are pushing tab bar controller onto a navigation controller stack. The view controllers of a tab bar will have a navigation item, but their navigation items aren't shown when the view controller is on screen. Instead, the tab bar controller's navigation item is on screen.

You could use `self.tabBarController.navigationItem`, but then each view controller will have to modify the navigation item every time it's brought on/off screen, which is really messy.

If you're going to use a UITabBarController, I would recommend either presenting it modally, or having it be the root view controller on your UIWindow. It's tough to get it working right as a view controller in a navigation controller's view controller stack.

Your tab bar item not showing its name is a separate issue. It's because viewDidLoad is getting called before you set your item instance, specifically it's getting called when you call `[tbc setViewControllers:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:photoHub, takeAPicture, nil]];`

You can confirm this by breakpointing in view did load, where you'll see that item is nil. If you haven't already, you should overload your setItem: method in PhotoCollectionViewController, and have that method also update your UI.